# Can the discriminant of a monic, irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ ever equal $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

For quadratic polynomials, say $x^2+bx+c$, the discriminant is given by $b^2-4c$.  If this equals $1$ (or even just a square), then the polynomial has rational roots and is not irreducible.  Does this trend continue to irreducible monics of greater degree?

More generally, is a lower bound known for the absolute value of the discriminant of irreducible, monic polynomials of a given degree? I know that the discriminant in this case must be an integer, and we have a trivial lower bound of $1$, by irreducibility.  What more can be said?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The discriminant can never be $\pm 1$. This follows from ramfication theory. If you let $\alpha$ be a root of your polynomial, then some prime will always ramify in the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and such a prime must divide the discriminant. This is called Minkowski's theorem. Look it up in any book on algebraic number theory.

The same theory tells us that $3$ is the smallest absolute value of the discriminant of any number field besides ${\mathbb{Q}}$. This absolute value happens for ${\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{-3})$. Given any monic irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and a root $\alpha$ of the polynomial, the discriminant of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ will always be less (in absolute value) than the discriminant of the polynomial (it's the discriminant of a polynomial divided by some of its square factors). Minkowki's theorem give us the following bound for the discriminant of a number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$:

$$\sqrt{|d_K|}\geq \frac{n^n}{n!}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{n/2}$$

The lower bound is strictly increasing for each $n$, so you can easily see that small discriminants are only possible for irreducible polynomials of small degree.

Since the discriminant of any number field beside ${\mathbb Q}$ has absolute value at least $3$ and there's an irreducible polynomial $X^2+X+1\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with discriminant $-3$, we see that $3$ is also the lower bound for the absolute value of the discriminant of any irreducible polynomial of degree greater than 1.

Comment: The question is about discriminants of *polynomials*, not discriminants of number fields, so you should remark on the relation between the two. If you allow rational coefficients you *can* get discriminant 1: $x^3 - x + 1/3$ and $x^3 - x - 1/3$ both have discriminant 1. Up to a change of variables $x' = x + c$ these are the only monic cubics with Q-coeff. and discrim. 1 (Kronecker).

Comment: The theorem of Kronecker I cited at the end of my previous comment uses Fermat's Last Theorem for exponent 3. See pp. 411--412 in Uspensky and Heaslet's Elementary Number Theory (McGraw-Hill, 1939).

Comment: The subject was about polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$, for rational coefficients it makes no sense.

Comment: pki: The point of the later part of my comment was to illustrate that if you omit the condition of the coefficients being integers then you can get cubics with discriminant 1 which are irreducible (a contrast to the quadratic case) and moreover the complete description of when this happens is closely related to FLT for exponent 3. I think that is interesting! Even if a question is asked just for ${\mathbf Z}[t]$, it can be worthwhile to see what happens if you look at it in ${\mathbf Q}[t]$ too.

Comment: KCd, you are correct. @pki, please note that the answers (and comments) are not only for the OP (asker?), but also it is a collection of related discussion etc, for future use. Let me try to explain: say another user asked about the case $Q[t]$. Then we can just refer to this problem. So, it is useful.